# GRUB issues - How to get back to windows boot manager

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, encryption

So I am dual-booting Windows and Ubuntu 16.04, and I have the Ubuntu partition encrypted. After updating yesterday my GRUB won't load. I tried using a live USB with boot-repair-disk but it wasn't able to do anything (possible due to the encryption??)

I don't have anything important saved on the linux partition but I do need access to Windows and I don't want to lose the files I have saved there. Is there a way to get windows boot manager to load? Or any other ways to fix GRUB for the time being? I don't mind deleting the linux partition and reinstalling Ubuntu (and maybe following a more up-to-date page for encrypting it.)

Comment: From Boot-Repair in Ubuntu live installer, mount your LVM and decrypt it. Then run the Summary Report and post link to the Summary report in question above. If UEFI/gpt system, you can always directly boot Windows from UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

If you use UEFI, you can boot Windows from the BIOS. (Press F12 or F10 or Escape directly after your cimputer starts)